# Exporting excel file with images- Reactjs

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs

I am developing a web app in React.js and I want to download an Excel file which includes images. I am using [react-data-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export) to generate an Excel file, however, I haven't got any idea how to include images in it. I found two examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/AnilAwadh/qt32a/

```
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) {
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r8bx18kx/

The problem is that I have no idea how to implement that in my case.